# Buy one get one in woocommerce with out coupon code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want implement functionality on my site when user buy a x product then user will get a y product as free.

In my site i have variable products.If customer buy 1kg pack of X product then customer want to get Free 30ml of Y product.

I added below code in my function.php but its working the problem is when refreshing the page gift product count is increasing.
**my updated code.**

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'bbloomer_apply_matched_coupons' );

function bbloomer_apply_matched_coupons() {

    global $woocommerce;
 $cat_in_cart = false;
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {

    // this is your product ID
    $autocoupon = array( 123411 );

    if( in_array( $values['variation_id'], $autocoupon ) ) {  
       $cat_in_cart = true;
        break;

    }


    }
 if ( $cat_in_cart ) {   
$product_id   = 2044;
$quantity     = 1;
$variation_id = 2046;
$variation    = array(
    'pa_size'  => '30ml'
);

$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation );
 }

}
```

Comment: You ask for help in one of my answers threads… So here is a different working answer. Please a feed back on it from you will be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to start of 'functions.php'.

```
ob_start();
session_start();
```

Then add this code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'bbloomer_apply_matched_coupons' );

function bbloomer_apply_matched_coupons() {

    if(!$_SESSION['GiftAdded']) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $cat_in_cart = false;
        $coupon_in_cart = false;

        $autocoupon = array( 123411 ); // variation ids of products that offers gifts
        $freecoupon = array( 2046 ); // variation ids of products that are gift coupons

        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {      
            if( in_array( $values['variation_id'], $autocoupon ) ) {  
                $cat_in_cart = true;                
            }
            if( in_array( $values['variation_id'], $freecoupon) ) {  
                $coupon_in_cart = true;             
            }
        }

         if ( $cat_in_cart && !$coupon_in_cart ) {   
            $product_id   = 2044;
            $quantity     = 1;
            $variation_id = 2046;
            $variation    = array( 'pa_size'  => '30ml' );

            $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation );
            $_SESSION['GiftAdded']=true;
        }
    }
}
```

The `$_SESSION['GiftAdded']` will prevent the gift product added again when its deleted manually.

Comment: but i added this code but each refresh the second product quantity increasing

Comment: You need to check your gift product's variation already in the cart before adding it, this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150953/check-if-a-product-variation-is-in-cart-in-woocommerce.

Comment: how i check that ?? i didn't understand that code well!!

Comment: Can you update your new variation code in your original question, so I will add the checking script?

Answer (score 1):

There is an other alternative based on quantity using another hook… It handles when quantities are changed or products removed from cart and set the price of the free product to zero:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_free_product_to_cart', 20, 1 );
function add_free_product_to_cart( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    $products_ids = array( 123411 ); // Products IDs to check
    $free_var_id  = 2046; // free product (variation ID)
    $free_prod_id = 2044; // free product (product ID)
    $free_attr    = array( 'pa_size'  => 'medium' ); // Free product attribute
    $free_price   = 0;

    $targeted = $free = array('qty' => 0 ); // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), $products_ids ) ) {
            $targeted['qty'] += $cart_item['quantity'];
        } elseif ( $cart_item['data']->get_id() == $free_var_id ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($free_price);
            $free['qty'] += $cart_item['quantity'];
            $free['key'] = $cart_item_key;
        }
    }
    // We exit (No changes are needed)
    if( $targeted['qty'] == $free['qty'] )
        return;

    if( $targeted['qty'] > 0 && $free['qty'] == 0 )
    {
        // Add the free product
        $cart->add_to_cart( $free_prod_id, $targeted['qty'], $free_var_id, $free_attr );
    }
    elseif(  $targeted['qty'] > 0 && $free['qty'] > 0 && $targeted['qty'] != $free['qty'] )
    {
        // Adjust free product quantity
        $cart->set_quantity( $free['key'], $targeted['qty'] );
    }
    elseif(  $targeted['qty'] == 0 && $free['qty'] > 0)
    {
        // Remove free product
        $cart->remove_cart_item( $free['key'] );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Comment: This code is also working for me but the free product deletion is not working

Comment: @developerme For me it does… Both products are perfectly sync…