# How to change the variable product price in cart also delete remove particular product form cart in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I my site i added one variable product in cart.At that time another variable product also added into that cart that product is gift product.Now i want to change the gift variable product price into 0 its working only at the time of condition meets the products that offers gifts in cart. Also i want to remove both product form same by clicking products that offers gifts.Below my code is not working for me.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_custom_price' );

function change_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 0; // This will be your custome price  
    $gift_variation_id = 2046;
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $value ) {
        if ( $value['variation_id'] == $gift_variation_id ) {
            $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gift item can be added as per this solution - [Buy one get one in woocommerce with out coupon code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589170/buy-one-get-one-in-woocommerce-with-out-coupon-code).

You can add the following to your theme's 'functions.php' to remove the gift item added automatically by another product.

```
function remove_gift_product($cart_item_key) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cat_in_cart = false;
    $coupon_in_cart = false;

    $autocoupon = array( 123411 ); // variation ids of products that offers gifts
    $freecoupon =  array( 2046 ); // variation ids of products that are gift coupons

    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {      
        if( in_array( $values['variation_id'], $autocoupon ) ) {  
            $cat_in_cart = true;                
        }       
    }

    if ( !$cat_in_cart ) {          
        foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
            if ( in_array( $cart_item['variation_id'], $freecoupon )) {             
                $woocommerce->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
            }
        } 
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'remove_gift_product' );
```

Add this if you want reduced price for your gift item.

```
function add_discount_price( $cart_object ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cat_in_cart = false;

    $autocoupon = array( 123411 ); // variation ids of products that offers gifts
    $freecoupon =  array( 2046 ); // variation ids of products that are gift coupons

    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {      
        if( in_array( $values['variation_id'], $autocoupon ) ) {  
            $cat_in_cart = true;                
        }       
    }
    if ( $cat_in_cart ) {
        $custom_price = 0; // This will be your custome price     
        foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
            if ( in_array( $cart_item['variation_id'], $freecoupon )) {
                 $cart_item['data']->set_price($custom_price);
            }        
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_discount_price' );
```

Comment: Hi i found one bug in this removing code. If i delete the free product in cart its not working

Comment: If you delete the main product, it will remove the free product - but why do you need to delete that free product?

Comment: The reason is free product automatically added to cart if main product exists as per - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589170/buy-one-get-one-in-woocommerce-with-out-coupon-code.

Comment: Any way to remove the free product only ??

Comment: Try updated answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589170/buy-one-get-one-in-woocommerce-with-out-coupon-code#51590498.